# Javascript: InnerHTML converts <br /> to <br>

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Javascript that gets an element by ID and inserts a text with a break line tag using the innerHTML method. The page is in XHTML 1.0 so I am using `<br />`.

```
var dom = document.getElementById(elmt);
var message = "This is a test";

dom.innerHTML = message + "<br />";
```

I have tested in Chrome and in IE and they both change the tag to `<br>`.
I am performing some .search with `<br />`, but it fails because it is not including the forward slash.
Is there a reason for this? How can I force it to send `<br />`?

Comment: I have tried `"<br &sol;/>"` and `"<br \/>"` and they both print `<br />`

Comment: works fine -- http://jsfiddle.net/qLb1e3zw/ -- you don't see the (/) in the html just the (<br>)

Comment: I am comparing the innerHTML. If you check with Firebug or whatever element inspector in the browser, you'll see that it converted to <br>. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/4zR7FuZ.png).

Comment: That's because In HTML, the <br> tag has no end tag. In XHTML, the <br> tag must be properly closed, like this: <br />. so in html (/) gets stripped off

Comment: Is there another way to go about this so that it validates to XHTML 1.0 strict then?

Comment: Not in HTML5 -- http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-relationship-between-html5-and-xhtml.html